# Why is the result of my query changing the expected result from "300" to what appears to be a superscript "L"?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm currently querying a MS SQL Server database through PHP and sqlsrv_connect protocol.  In my table, there is a column with file locations:

> \\FILESERVER123\IDImages\Photos\003741.jpg

I'm then utilizing PHP's str_replace() to convert this to a URL:

```
$imglink = str_replace('\\\\FILESERVER123\\IDImages\\Photos','http://webserver/idphotos/',$row['SeeExampleAbove'])
```

The "003" is being converted into what looks like a superscript "L" at some point.  It appears to be happening in the initial query and not during the str_replace(), but I'm at a loss as to why and my Google skills aren't helping this time.

Is it something to do with character encoding?

Comment: Where does it show up as a superscript L? I can only guess that it's some sort of hex/ascii code.

Comment: The value stored in the database shows "003" mid-string when viewed through SQL Server Management Studio.  When I query the database, the resulting string shows a superscript "L" where the "003" should be.  I've just noticed another example where "011" in the table was converted to a series of spaces after the query.  If I copy-paste directly from SQL Server Management Studio into Notepad, the URL pastes as expected.

Comment: Escape the backslashes. Use of \ in a string has weird outcomes. Change them to \\, which escapes back to \. Or, replace them with something like / until you need them reveresed to be \.

Comment: Then it's probably something to do with the SQL Server Management Studio, converting the string bits to something else.

Comment: Correct. I strongly believe it is looking odd on display, not in the database. When the SQL editor tries to display the value, it sees \ as an escape character and treats it as such.

Comment: I'm escaping the "\" characters in the search portion of the str_replace() function (see my original post).  The conversion seems to occur during the initial query result, not the str_replace() function.  Octal Code "011" is listed as a horizontal tab which would explain the follow-up note, but not the "300" problem.

Comment: You are not escaping the \ after Photos. So, you end up with a \ in your final URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not escaping the \ after Photos. So, you end up with a \ in your final URL.

That's just so you can have this as a correct answer. But, since this is an answer, I feel it is necessary to explain...

For most programming languages (PHP included), the \ character is used as an escape character in strings. Between " and " (often between ' and ' also), the \ is used to indicate that the following character has special meaning. For example, "This \" prints the quotes". The \" means that the " after the \ is not the end of the string.

Because \ has special meaning, to print \ you need to escape it using \. Two \ characters are interpretted as a single .

Many languages let you use \ to enter characters using codes. You type \ and then you type the numeric code of the character you want. In this question, the \ was followed by a number (003 in one example and 011 in another). The computer translated those to a character (likely a unicode character).

The source of this problem is Windows, or MS-DOS to be exact. Long before MS-DOS (and Windows), heiarchical file systems used / to separate directories and files. For an unknown reason, QDOS, which because MS-DOS, opted to use . Now, when a Windows user refers to a location in the file system, he or she has to escape all the \ characters as \. But it doesn't have to be that hard. I've experimented with PHP in Windows 7 and 10. If I refer to "c:/users/myuser/downloads/somefile.jpg", it works just fine. PHP's file handler understands that I am typing / but it needs to use \ for the operating system. It is translated for me (Yay 4th Generation Programming Languages!). Therefore, this entire problem could have been solved by replacing all \ characters with / characters from the beginning.

What ended up happening is that the replacement left one \ in the file's path name. That wasn't escaped as \ and was translated as being a special character.

Comment: Excellent write-up!  Thanks again, kainaw.  As an addendum, this is an excellent example of why you should sometimes step away from an issue for a few minutes when you're unable to find an error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> You are not escaping the \ after Photos. So, you end up with a \ in your final URL. – kainaw 27 mins ago

It was as simple as that.  I spent WAAAY too much time troubleshooting this one.  Thanks to everyone for your responses.